# Adding values to object in js

Tags: javascript

So, I have the following js object structure:

[image]

I am trying to add a value to this, for example, "234324" after "ewerewr".

I tried `obj["d7vi"] = new_value;`

But it gets rid of all the previous values.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make it

```
obj["d7vi"].push(newValue);
```

you need to add to the array rather than replace its existing values.